# Obtener los valores de un objeto que está anidado dentro de otro objeto anidado en Mongoose y Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, mongoose

Estoy empezando en MongoDB. Llevo varios días con este problema, he encontrado soluciones donde solo obtengo el primer objeto anidado dentro de otro. Lo que deseo es **obtener los valores de un objeto que está anidado dentro de otro objeto anidado**. No sé si estoy trabajando bien en el diseño de los esquemas o es un problema en mi código en Vuejs para obtener los documentos anidados.

Tengo los siguiente schemas:

```
//Schema Categoria
const categoriaSchema = new Schema ({
    nombreCategoria: {type: String, required: [true, 'Nombre de categoría obligatorio.']},
    tiempoRetiro: {type: Number, required: [true, 'Tiempo de retiro obligatorio.']}
});

//Schema Articulo
const articuloSchema = new Schema ({
    codigoArticulo: {type: Number, required: [true, 'Código de arículo obligatorio.']},
    nombreArticulo: {type: String, required: [true, 'Nombre de artícuo obligatorio.']},
    categoriaArticulo: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: Categoria} //Hago referencia a Categoria
});

//Schema Registro
const registroSchema = new Schema ({
    fechaIngresoArticulo: {type: Date, required: true},
    fechaVencimientoArticulo: {type: Date, required: [true, 'Fecha de vencimiento obligatorio.']},
    datosArticulo: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: Articulo} //Hago referencia a Articulo
});
```

Al ejecutar el siguiente código para obtener datos del Articulo en Articulo.vue

```
listarArticulos() {
        this.axios.get('/articulo')
        .then(res => {
            this.articulos = res.data;
            console.log(this.articulos);

        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.log(e.response);
        })
    }
```

Obtengo por consola lo siguiente:

```
categoriaArticulo: (Object)
    nombreCategoria: "GASEOSAS"
    tiempoRetiro: 15
    _id: "6179baf4a056c5e8b99c08e6"
codigoArticulo: 852852
nombreArticulo: "COCA COLA 2.5 L"
id: "6179cb860aa31f257f29af66"
```

Como pueden notar, también obtengo el objeto **categoriaArticulo** (Categoria) con sus valores, al que hice referencia en el Schema **Articulo**. Del cual, solo en este caso, necesito el **nombreCategoria**. Hasta aquí todo va bien.

Mi problema surge cuando quiero, a través de **datosArticulo** (Articulo), obtener el valor **vidaUtil** dentro de **categoriaArticulo** (Categoria); y ejecuto el siguiente código en Registros.vue guiándome del anterior:

```
listarRegistros() {
        this.axios.get('/registro')
        .then(res => {
            this.registros = res.data;
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.log(e.response);
        })
    }
```

Y obtengo por consola lo siguiente:

```
datosArticulo: (Object)
    categoriaArticulo: "6179baf4a056c5e8b99c08e6" //Como pueden observar, aquí me nuestra el _id de Categoria y NO un objeto como en el anterior.
    codigoArticulo: 852852
    nombreArticulo: "COCA COLA 2.5 L"
    _id: "6179cb860aa31f257f29af66"
fechaIngresoArticulo: "2021-11-18T05:00:00.000Z"
fechaVencimientoArticulo: "0202-12-31T05:08:12.000Z"
_id: "6196b59190eec332e1820292"
```

Lo que deseo es obtener es el objeto **categoriaArticulo** (Categoria) dentro de **datosArticulo** (Articulo), como muestro a continuación:

```
datosArticulo: (Object)
    categoriaArticulo: (Object) //Objeto que deseo obtener
        nombreCategoria: "GASEOSAS"
        tiempoRetiro: 15
        _id: "6179baf4a056c5e8b99c08e6"
    codigoArticulo: 852852
    nombreArticulo: "COCA COLA 2.5 L"
    _id: "6179cb860aa31f257f29af66"
fechaIngresoArticulo: "2021-11-18T05:00:00.000Z"
fechaVencimientoArticulo: "0202-12-31T05:08:12.000Z"
_id: "6196b59190eec332e1820292"
```

Agradezco por su tiempo y espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Hola, no veo el codigo de mongoose.

Comment: Hola. Estoy trabajando en el archivo Registros.vue, no con código en mongoose. Lo que quiero es listar en consola tal como mencioné al final. Intenté con .populate(), pero creo no lo apliqué bien. Gracias por tu interés.

Answer (score 0):

## [`.populate()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate) es lo que buscas.

Debería ser algo así:

```
Categoria.find().populate('categoriaArticulo').exec()
```

Si tu campo esta bien referenciado debería funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Ya pude solucionarlo. Mi problema estaba en el back-end, al momento de llamar los documentos. Solo usaba populate() para el primer objeto, era poblar múltiples niveles:

```
router.get('/registro', async(req, res) => {
try {
    const registroDB = await Registro.find().populate({ path: 'datosArticulo', populate: { path: 'categoriaArticulo' }}); //poblar multiples niveles
    res.json(registroDB)
} catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).json({
        mensaje: 'Ocurrió un error',
        error
    })
}});
```